# Function with with consecutive brackets

Tags: notation

What is the meaning of a function like:

$f(x)(y)$

It seems to me that this is another way to express the composition of function $f$ with function $x$. Am I right? But then why don't just use the "usual notation" $f \circ x$?

Comment: Thank you for editing, yes I meant \circ. I didn't know the code for typing it

Answer (score 0):

That's not how I would interpret f(x)(y).  The composition of the function f(x) and x(y) would be written f(x(y)).  The only reasonable interpretation of f(x)(y) that I can see would be "f(x) times y".

Non-mathematics note: while a function of two variables would be written, in mathematics, as f(x,y), some computer languages use f(x)(y).